# Chrome POST/GET data affecting inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have searched through all the chrome onclick issues on here and none are like the issue I am experiencing.

I have a div, which I am putting an onclick event on (in PHP) like so...

```
$design_code = '<div class="skip" onclick="skipOffer2();">'.$design.'</div>';
```

In IE & FF this works fine. In Chrome, it works roughly 50% of the time. When it doesn't work and I examine this div using Firebug on Chrome it shows an empty onclick event:

```
<div class="skip" onclick="">
```

I do not have any code that removes this event, overrides it, or does anything with that div whatsoever, and again... it's only happening on Chrome. Somehow Chrome is removing this event.

To add more confusion to the mix, when I prepend the onclick function with "javascript:" it works 100% in Chrome.

```
$design_code = '<div class="skip" onclick="javascript:skipOffer2();">'.$design.'</div>';
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is Chrome really removing my event handler and why? Lastly, why would prepending "javascript:" fix the issue?

---

UPDATE 1:
The issue actually has to do with POST data passed from the previous page. I am passing a urlencoded string from the previous page which contains the text "onclick%3D%22skipOffer2%28%29%22".

On the current page, I cannot use this onclick function at all! If I try to use onclick="skipOffer2()" Chrome will remove it and leave an empty onclick event.

How is the POST data (that is not even being used) affecting the current page? Can someone else verify this?

Here is my test url: http://mattkeaveney.com/test1.php

---

UPDATE 2:
Problem exists with GET data too..

http://mattkeaveney.com/test2.php?test=onclick%253D%2522alertMe%2528%2529%2522

Comment: Practice [behavioral separation](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation)...

Comment: True, unobtrusive javascript is another way of going at it but doesn't explain the problems experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I googled "chrome bugs onclick" and there are many pages of reports of the problem.  As to the why, I think Google is still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be passing arbitrary JS through the GET or POST to be executed on the page. Doing so opens you up Cross-Site Scripting and many other security vulnerabilities.

Chrome is likely filtering out the JS to prevent from these types of attacks. The offer a header to bypass this filtering, but you should really just re-architect your website.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, the JS I'm passing through GET/POST is not being executed on the page- I'm not even accessing that data in any way! See my example link. It's not even complete JS. It's actually just a string, and a urlencoded string at that.